# Insert value with NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert the data into facilities_details table that doesn't exits in the table, below code cannot run properly.

```
$facility = $_POST["facilities_cb"];
foreach ($facility as $feature)
{
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO facilities_details(facilitiestype_id,hotel_id) values ('$feature','$hid') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT facilitiestype_id FROM facilities_details)");
}
```

Comment: I think you want a UNIQUE constraint instead.

Comment: `WHERE` is not a proper part of the `INSERT` command.

Comment: @Hello was you problem solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
insert into facilities_details (facilitiestype_id, hotel_id) 
select $feature, $hid where not exists (
    select 1 from facilities_details where facilitiestype_id = $feature and hotel_id = $hid
)
```

or this

```
insert into facilities_details (facilitiestype_id, hotel_id) 
select $feature, $hid where not exists (
    select 1 from facilities_details where facilitiestype_id = $feature
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such syntax `WHERE` cannot be used with `INSERT`. If you wanted to ignore `INSERT` when data exists, then you could use `INSERT IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO facilities_details(facilitiestype_id,hotel_id)
VALUES ('$feature','$hid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT facilitiestype_id
   FROM facilities_details)
INSERT INTO facilities_details(facilitiestype_id,hotel_id)
VALUES ('$feature',
        '$hid');
```

Comment: This will only allow a total of one row in the table. Probably not what OP is looking for.